# Adding event handlers by using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls

I am adding dynamically controls to page by using LoadControl and Controls.Add. I need somehow to wrap Init and Load event handlers of this loaded controls into my code. So it should be such order of events *SomeMyCode() -> Control.Init() -> AnotherMyCode()* and the same for Load *SomeMyCode() -> Control.Load() -> AnotherMyCode()*.
My idea was to Get List of Control's event handlers for Init and Load events and add first and last event handers with code I should to run. But I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: Are you really down-voting the answers that don't work for you? Please only down-vote them if they're malicious, and up-vote the ones that move you any closer to a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* forcibly inject an event handler in front of other handlers already subscribed to an event. If you need method A to be called first, then you'll need to subscribe A first.

---

Re your comment, that is incredibly hacky. First, you can't even rely on an event having a delegate-field backer; it can be an `EventHandlerList` or other - which don't nevessarily expose handy hooks short of reversing the removal.

Second (and more important), it breaks every rule of encapsulation.

In general, if you want to be first, the *best* approach is to override the `OnFoo()` method. The second-best is to subscribe first.

Comment: Yes I know. But I can use GetInovocationList to obtain all delegates and then add them in needed order

Comment: Yes, this approach is not so clean but in any case it works. I think that disallowing to get this events in more strict way it's bad design form MS.

Comment: @Horseman - and I think that the design is *correct* to be strict about this. The "bad design", frankly, is your choosing to disregard encapsulation. So be it...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a draft of a working solution:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control ctrl = this.LoadControl("WebUserControl1.ascx");
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Control).GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
        EventHandlerList eventHandlerList = propertyInfo.GetValue(ctrl, new object[]{}) as EventHandlerList;
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(Control).GetField("EventLoad", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

        if(fieldInfo == null)
            return;

        object eventKey = fieldInfo.GetValue(ctrl);
        Delegate eventHandler = eventHandlerList[eventKey] as Delegate;

        foreach(EventHandler item in eventHandler.GetInvocationList()) {
            ctrl.Load -= item;
        }

        ctrl.Load += ctrl_Load;
        foreach (EventHandler item in eventHandler.GetInvocationList()){
            ctrl.Load += item;
        }
        ctrl.Load += ctrl_Load;

        this.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    }

    void ctrl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```